# Выдает ошибку "Не удалось определить связь между двумя объектами, поскольку они привязаны к разным объектам ObjectContext"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Мне нужно реализовать добавление курса в список курсов, на которые зарегистрировался студент, я это и делаю в методе `AddCourseToStudent`, но на строке `db.SaveChanges();` программа падает.

```
public void AddCourseToStudent(Course course, Student student)
{
    Student nStudent = new Student();
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        nStudent = db.Students.Find(student.Id);
        db.Entry(nStudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
        nStudent.Courses.Add(course);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Это реализация контекста:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Mark> Marks { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

А это инициализация студента:

```
var students = new List<Student>()
{
    new Student{ Name = "Данил", Surname = "Евтушенко", Email = "somemail@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[0], courses[1], courses[2], courses[3], courses[4], courses[5], courses[6], courses[7] } },
    new Student{ Name = "Владислав", Surname = "Коваленко", Email = "somemail1@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[0], courses[1], courses[3], courses[4], courses[5] }  },
    new Student{ Name = "Николай", Surname = "Панченко", Email = "somemail2@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[2], courses[1], courses[2], courses[3], courses[4], courses[5], courses[6] }  },
    new Student{ Name = "Анатолий", Surname = "Берко", Email = "somemail3@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[3], courses[1], courses[3], courses[4] }  },
    new Student{ Name = "Ольга", Surname = "Шаповал", Email = "somemail4@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[1], courses[3], courses[4] }  },
    new Student{ Name = "Виктория", Surname = "Плюйко", Email = "somemail5@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[0], courses[3], courses[7], courses[4] }  },
    new Student{ Name = "Анна", Surname = "Застава", Email = "somemail6@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[0], courses[2], courses[3], courses[4], courses[5], courses[6] }  },
    new Student{ Name = "Алена", Surname = "Ганжа", Email = "somemail7@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[0], courses[2], courses[6], courses[7] }  },
    new Student{ Name = "Степан", Surname = "Шеремет", Email = "somemail8@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[2], courses[1], courses[6], courses[7] }  },
    new Student{ Name = "Дмитрий", Surname = "Крижановский", Email = "somemail9@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[0], courses[3] }  },
    new Student{ Name = "Данил", Surname = "Волков", Email = "somemail10@mail.ru", Courses = new List<Course>{ courses[0], courses[6], courses[7] }  },
};
students.ForEach(s => context.Students.Add(s));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: попробуйте `db.Courses.Attach(course);`  перед `nStudent.Courses.Add(course);`

Comment: Вы не можете использовать объект полученный от одного контекста в другом контексте, если не сделали его Detach и Attach. Грубо говоря ваш Course объект получен не из текущего объекта `ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext()`, а откуда-то еще и EF это видит, следовательно попытка его прицепить проваливается.

Comment: может потому что у вас связь между сущностями определена не верно?

Comment: Не удалось присоединить сущность типа "ProjectDatabase.Models.Student", поскольку другая сущность этого же типа уже имеет такое же значение первичного ключа. Такое возможно при использовании метода "Attach" или задании сущности состояния "Unchanged" или "Modified", если какие-либо сущности в графе имеют конфликтующие значения ключей. Такое возможно из-за того, что некоторые сущности являются новыми и пока еще не получили значения ключей, сформированные базой данных.

Comment: Ну ошибка все еще указывает на то, что было сказано выше: вы не можете просто так использовать объект полученный от одного контекста в другом контексте. Контекст - это конкретный объект вашего класса `new ApplicationDbContext()`. Если создали два разных, то сущности полученные с помощью них мешать нельзя. Сначала надо отсоединить сущность от старого контекста и только потом присоединять к новому. Ну или сделайте выборку заново `var courseEntity = db.Courses.Find(course.Id);` на худой конец и добавляйте ее к студенту.

Comment: Тоисть мне надо все переменные (абсолютно все: course, student и т. д.) для работы с данным методом получить от одного контекста?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо большое))

Comment: Ну и чтобы вы знали, есть еще второй вариант - переменная отвязывается от старого контекста и привязывается к новому. Отвязывается она так: `старыйКонтекст.Entry(course).State = EntityState.Detached;`, либо во время получения указывается, что за ней не надо следить через `AsNoTracking`: `старыйКонтекст.Courses.AsNoTracking().Where(...).Select(...);`... иногда можно встретить `старыйКонтекст.Detach(course)`. И потом вы можете ее привязать к новому контексту: `новыйКонтекст.Courses.Attach(course);` или `новыйКонтекст.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.ВыбратьПоЖеланию;`.

Answer (score 1):

Внутри себя Entity Framework имеет механизм, который следит за всеми сущностями, которые получены из контекста. Поэтому вы можете при исследовании объектов обнаружить ссылки между контекстом и сущности. К примеру в сущности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому когда объект изменяется, то контекст получает уведомление об изменении и в случае вызова SaveChanges() правильно обновляет сущности в базе данных. Даже если вы ему явно об этом ничего не говорили.

```
Context ctx = new Context();
var item = ctx.Item.First();
item.Value = "new value"; // никаких явных уведомлений в контекст нет
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Отсюда есть ряд особенностей, в частности нельзя сущность от одного контекста сохранить в сущности от другого контекста. При подобной попытке произойдет ошибка.

```
Context ctx = new Context();
var link = ctx.Item.First();

Context ctx2 = new Context();
var item = ctx.Item.Last();
item.Links.Add(link);
ctx2.SaveChanges(); // ошибка
```

Поскольку мы пытаемся привязать сущность от первого контекста к сущности от второго контекста, то в итоге получим ошибку.

**Решение 1**

Использовать сущности только из одного контекста:

```
public void AddCourseToStudent(Course course, Student student)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var tempCourse = db.Courses.Find(course.Id);
        var tempStudent = db.Students.Find(student.Id);
        tempStudent .Courses.Add(tempCourse);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Решение 2**

Явно отсоединять сущность от первого контекста и привязывать ко второму контексту. При этом для отвязывания могут использоваться разные способы. Либо через AsNoTracking():

```
Context ctx = new Context();
var link = ctx.Item.AsNoTracking().First();

Context ctx2 = new Context();
ctx2.Item.Attach(link);

var item = ctx.Item.Last();
item.Links.Add(link);
ctx2.SaveChanges();
```

Либо через Detach:

```
Context ctx = new Context();
var link = ctx.Item().First();
ctx.Entry(link).State = EntityState.Detached;

Context ctx2 = new Context();
ctx2.Item.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

var item = ctx.Item.Last();
item.Links.Add(link);
ctx2.SaveChanges();
```